# how to send whole json data back as response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am about to learn Rails, and i got a simple question

If i have a function :

```
def create 
 render:json params[:all]
end
```

my create function is defined as POST and accept json as incomming data, how do i return all the json data back as request?

usually i see people do stuff like this:

```
def create
 @user  = User.new( params.require(:user).permit(:data))
  if @user.save
    render json: @user,status 200
.....
```

P.S. Second question where does call to database functions belongs? In ASP.NET i usually create a repository class and all the calls to db ends up there, but what is the correct way in Rails?

Comment: These are two very different questions. If you take a basic Rails tutorial, they will be answered.

Comment: `User.new` basically invokes the repository for you. It uses ActiveRecord ORM.

Comment: I know what user.new does, its more about if i have to seach for specific record or something, and i dont want to write 10 lines of same code all over the place.

Comment: @MarkThomas I took the tutorial on rails website, but it didnt answer my questions. Therefor i am here

Comment: That's fine, but your "second question" should be a separate SO question (with a bit more specifics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
  render json: params
end
```

will return the params as JSON.

"params[:all]" will only return the contents of the :all key in the params hash.